# Registering a user using POST - how to correctly use ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, json, spring, http

I'm building REST API (not public, just for my own site's backend) and I have a Controller for registering new User:

```
  // CREATE A USER
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(
        @RequestBody User user
) {
    if (userService.userExists(user)) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("User with that username already exists.");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.saveUser(user));
}
```

I don't like that String in my ResponseEntity when username is already taken - what is the correct way to handle those things? I know I should be returning JSONs from all of my controllers but I don't know how to implement that in that method.

Also is returning in JSON only a username fine in this controller:

```
// DELETE YOUR ACCOUNT - deletes logged in user
@DeleteMapping("/delete")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUser(Principal principal) {
    userService.deleteUser(principal);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(principal.getName());
}
```

I'm still very confused about what to return in REST Controllers - does everything have to be just JSONs (I know that I can use XML too (and some others) but chose JSONs) + status codes? Is that going to be easy to use when I try to build front-end for that webapp?

Comment: DELETE and UPDATE could return number of lines deleted or updated - 1 or 0 in your case.

Comment: I'm working with Entities and db - what do you mean by deleted lines? I' just curious how it should be done the correct way implementation-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this can be any help

```
// CREATE A USER
@PostMapping("/register")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<JSONObject> createUser( @RequestBody User user ) {

    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();

    if (userService.userExists(user)) {

        responseJson.put("status", "User with that username already exists.");

        return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(responseJson, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    responseJson.put("status", "User created.");

    return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(responseJson, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convenient approach to do it with [optional](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/java8):

```
    @PostMapping("/register")
    /* */
    Optional<User> optionalUser = userService.findUserById(userId);
    // or userService.findUserByName(username);
    return Optional.ofNullable(optionalUser)
        .map(u -> {
                 return getBadRequestResponse(Sting.format("User with name : %s already exists", username));
             }
        ).orElse(getSuccessfulResponse(
                     new userService.addUser(user)));

[...]

  protected ResponseEntity getSuccessfulResponse(Object result) {
     return new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  protected ResponseEntity getBadRequestResponse(String message) {
    return new ResponseEntity(new RestErrorResponse(message),   HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
```